# GetasyncKeyState() not working in C++

Tags: c++, keyboard, directx

I have thew following code:

```
void InitDirect3DApp::updateScene(float dt)
{
    D3DApp::updateScene(dt);

    // Update angles based on input to orbit camera around box.
    if(GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000) mTheta -= 2.0f*dt;
    if(GetKeyState('D') & 0x8000) mTheta += 2.0f*dt;
    if(GetKeyState('W') & 0x8000) mPhi -= 2.0f*dt;
    if(GetKeyState('S') & 0x8000) mPhi += 2.0f*dt;


    // Restrict the angle mPhi.
    if( mPhi < 0.1f ) mPhi = 0.1f;
    if (mPhi > PI - 0.1f) mPhi = PI-0.1f;

    // Convert Spherical to Cartesian coordinates: mPhi measured from +y
    // and mTheta measured counterclockwise from -z.
    float x = 5.0f * sinf(mPhi) * sinf(mTheta);
    float z = -5.0f * sinf(mPhi) * cosf(mTheta);
    float y = 5.0f * cosf(mPhi);

    // Build the view matrix.
    D3DXVECTOR3 pos(x, y, z);
    D3DXVECTOR3 target(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXVECTOR3 up(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&mView, &pos, &target, &up);
}
```

Problem is that the code inside the if statements after GetKeyState is not run no matter if the relevant keys are pressed.  I've tried upper case and lower case, but GetKeyState doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm using Visual C++ 2008 Express on Windows 8.1

UPDATE:
Here is the code I have for the message pump:

```
MSG msg = { 0 };

mTimer.reset();

while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    // If there are Window messages then process them.
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    // Otherwise, do animation/game stuff.
    else
    {
        mTimer.tick();

        if (!mAppPaused)
            updateScene(mTimer.getDeltaTime());
        else
            Sleep(50);

        drawScene();
    }
}
return (int)msg.wParam;
```

I have also tried getasynckeystate with the same result.

Comment: The [`GetKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference says: "An application calls **`GetKeyState`** in response to a keyboard-input message." It might not work if you try to fetch it otherwise.

Comment: What about GetAsyncKeyState?  It seems to work on other projects,  but this one doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Using `GetKeyState` in this way will not work. You probably should use `GetKeyboardState`, to get the whole keyboard state once per frame and test individual keys like you are doing here. `GetAsyncKeyState` might work too, I don't know. However, keep in mind that testing keyboard events while also breaking in and out of a debugger might be a little frustrating because of all the key state changes that happen between frames inside the debugger.

Comment: Well this is code i got from a book.  It works on one particular project but not this one.  I can't work out why.

Comment: Can someone help please?   I need to know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I reset the computer and now the code works!  Got no idea why, I guess something just needed a refresh or something.